Plot fails to plot. What am I doing wrong?
The below code executes.  If I uncomment the Plot, it runs for a while and outputs nothing, not even the Mean and Variance.

new2 = TransformedDistribution[(x + y + z)/3, {x, y,z} \[Distributed] LogMultinormalDistribution[{0,1,0},{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}]];

lmdpdf = PDF[new2,x];

(* Plot[%, {x, 1, 8}, Filling -> Axis,PlotRange -> Automatic]  *)

Mean[new2]
Variance[new2]

========
Meanwhile, the below works fine.

new2a = TransformedDistribution[(x + y),
 {x\[Distributed] NormalDistribution[],
y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]} 
];

PDF[new2a, x];

Plot[%, {x, -6, 8}, Filling -> Axis,PlotRange -> Automatic]

Mean[new2a]
Variance[new2a]

===
ADDED in response to comment.  The below runs fine, including plot. I think it is the same as a 2 variable version of my non-plotting Transform.
===
new2a = TransformedDistribution[(x + y),
 {x\[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[0,1],
y \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[0,1]
} 
]

Added more: tried exactly two variable version, and it fails to plot.  Sans Plot function, it returns the same Mean and Variance though, so I am even more confused.  This is apparently not a Plot issue, but a closed/open form issue combined with a built-in-symbols question...
new2 = TransformedDistribution[(x + y + z), {x,y,z} \[Distributed] LogMultinormalDistribution[{0,1,0},{{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}]];

dividing by 2 (see below) also causes code to fail, which doesn't feel like it is a closed/open form issue, but I have no idea what MMA is doing under the covers ...
new2a = TransformedDistribution[(x + y)/2,
 {x\[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[0,1],
y \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[0,1]
} 
]



There is no closed-form for that pdf and it must be evaluated numerically.  Hence, no plot.

Your distribution is a distribution in THREE variables, not ONE.

@DavidG.Stork No.  The resulting distribution (new2) is a univariate distribution.

I should have given a more comprehensive comment:  There is no closed-form solution for random variables proportional to the sum of 2 or more lognormal distributions.  That includes the mean of 2 or more independent lognormals.  But there are numerical approximations.  It might not feel like a closed-form issue but it is.  It is not a Mathematica issue.  (It might be nice if Mathematica would give a warning stating that there is no closed-form pdf but for this case that fact is well-known.)

@JimB If I take the sum instead of the mean, it still fails. Except in the case of exactly two variables and a slightly different implementation.  I have appended those to my post. (had attached prior to your comment, so some things (like me asking about sum vs mean) are now irrelevant.

I don't know how I can make it any clearer:  there is no closed-form pdf for sums of lognormal random variables.  A Google search on "sum of lognormal random variables" will also tell you that.  And that includes the pdf for means (which is the sum divided by the number of lognormal random variables).  There are approximations (as in my answer below) and numerical integration approaches.  Look at the Related Distributions section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution where it explicitly states that there are no closed-form solutions for the distribution (pdf or cdf).

@JimB I believe everything you are saying, and I think I understand it.  Your prior comment was great. I am left boggling that the code that I stated works - which is TD of two LNDs  -works.  I pasted an image of the output, including the Plot.  From what you explained, that should be impossible.  What am I missing?

I see.  (I hate it when I'm wrong.)  I'll look into this in more detail....

It appears that putting in machine precision numbers (such as PDF[new2a, 3.5]) allows Mathematica to produce a density.  PDF[new2a, 7/2]  doesn't return a density.  So maybe there's an underlying NPDF function (similar to NIntegrate).  More to think about.

My guess now is that when a machine precision number is given to PDF and Mathematica recognizes that the distribution is the sum of two independent random variables, numerical convolution is used.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions.  But it doesn't do this for a sum of 3 or more independent random variables.  Plot feeds PDF with machine precision numbers so it works.  And there still isn't a closed-form solution.

@JimB  Thank you.  pre-post, I had started all this by verifying the sum-of-two worked, and assumed if MMA handled 2 it could handle 3+ in the same way, and off I went.

Looking at the documentation for PDF (which I should have done earlier) under "Possible Issues" shows an example where the closed-form does not exist (and not for a sum of 2 independent random variables) but evaluates the pdf numerically.  So there are multiple circumstances where PDF can kick into numerical mode.

If you just need a display of an approximation of the pdf, random sampling with a large sample and a SmoothHistogram works fine for your particular distribution.
x = RandomVariate[new2, 1000000];
SmoothHistogram[x, PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, Automatic}}]


If you need a function that gives the approximate value of the pdf and more accurate than SmoothHistogram because we know that the pdf is bounded on the left by zero, then using random sampling with a large sample and SmoothKernelDistribution works:
skd = SmoothKernelDistribution[x, Automatic, {"Bounded", {0, ∞}, "Gaussian"},
  MaxMixtureKernels -> 1000, InterpolationPoints -> 1000];
Plot[PDF[skd, z], {z, 0, 15}]


If you and interested in a more direct numerical integration solution, then that should be added to your question.

Thank you.  That has spawned new questions in two different directions. I will write them up and link them here.
